# c# razor if statement not working

Tags: c#, razor

I am being asked do make some changes to a webpage buid with Umbraco of which I have almost no knowledge and a very basic understanding of C#.

This is the offending bit of the code:

```
@foreach (DynamicNode child in root.Children)
        {
            string image = @child.GetProperty("image").Value;
            var imgURL = Model.MediaById(image).url;
            var extURL = @child.GetProperty("externalURL").Value;
            var fullURL = "http://" + extURL;

            string externalLinks = child.GetProperty("externalDocuments").Value;
            string downloadsFolderId = @child.GetProperty("downloadsFolder").Value;
            string brandName = child.GetProperty("brandName").Value;
            bool brandCheck = brandName.Contains("Generic");

            if (brandCheck == true)
            {
              string brandHeader = "<h2 class='blue' title='"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+"'>"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+" <span></span></h2>";
            }
            else
            {
              string brandHeader = "<h2 class='red' title='"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+"'>"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+" <span></span></h2>";
            }

            //Links
            <span style="display:none" id="tester" >@brandCheck</span>
            <div class="brand-container">
                @Html.Raw(brandHeader)
```

So essentially I need to check if the returned name of product contains string "Generic". If it does, apply class "blue", if not apply class "red" - sound easy enough.

The string search works ok because the hidden @brandCheck return true or false values accordingly. Also if I remove the if statement and define the string brandHeader, it will be correctly generated on the (in the above code) last line (@html.Raw(brandHeader).

Clearly the issue is the if statement. I tried:

- if(brandCheck ==  true)
- if(brandCheck ===  true)
- if(brandCheck == 'true')
- if(brandCheck ===  'true')
- if(brandCheck)

but nothing seems to work, the if statement will crash the script. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It looks like you need to define the `brandHeader` outside of the `if`...

Comment: Are you sure that `brandName` has value when you call `Contains` on it?

Comment: i tried this string brandHeader ="" and then on the if statement brandHeader = "{html string}" but still nothing :(

Comment: What is "crashes"? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and replace

```
bool brandCheck = brandName.Contains("Generic");

if (brandCheck == true)
{
     string brandHeader = "<h2 class='blue' title='"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+"'>"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+" <span></span></h2>";
}
else
{
     string brandHeader = "<h2 class='red' title='"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+"'>"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+" <span></span></h2>";
}
```

with

```
string brandHeader = string.Format("<h2 class='{0}' title='"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+"'>"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+" <span></span></h2>", brandName.Contains("Generic") ? "blue" : "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the if-clause crashing your program, but rather the fact that your

```
string brandHeader
```

is only defined inside the if clause.

If you access it later on, it is not defined anymore, causing your script to crash (In other words: As soon as you leave your if-clause, your `string brandHeader` is out of scope).

As a workaround, put the

```
string brandHeader;
```

outside your if-clause, and in the if-clause only assign the value by

```
brandheader = < value >;
```

without the string at the beginning.

Comment: `bool brandCheck = brandName.Contains("Generic");
            string brandHeader;
            if(brandCheck)
            {
              brandHeader = "<h2 class='blue' title='"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+"'>"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+" <span></span></h2>";
            }
            else
            {
              brandHeader = "<h2 class='red' title='"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+"'>"+@child.GetProperty("brandName").Value+" <span></span></h2>";
            }` I get "Error loading MacroEngine script (file: /pws/Brand.cshtml)"